# What makes the object.prototype to the constructor function if he has no name?

Tags: javascript, function, class, inheritance, prototype

My following code is this:

```
 var triangle = {a:1, b:2, c:3};

function constructorFunction() {
  this.color = "red";
}

constructorFunction.prototype = triangle;
```

I know that the prototype keyword extends classes in this syntax: `Object.prototype.method = function() {}` But what for is this example? after `constructorFunction.prototype` there is no property or method name, what happens here?

Comment: No, this is a little different.

Comment: `prototype` is not a keyword. `.prototype` is a simple property of the `constructorFunction`.

Comment: `.prototype` works only with `new` operator.
To set _real_ [[[prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Inheritance_with_the_prototype_chain)]] (internal link, \__proto__) without using `.prototype`, Use `Object.create( real_prototype )` or `Object.setPrototypeOf( existing_object, new_real_prototype)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> after constructorFunction.prototype there is no propertie or method name

That's not true. The `prototype` of the constructor is set using `triangle` object. The `prototype` has 3 properties.

`prototype` is an object. Consider these examples:

```
var obj = { 'baz': 'bar' };
obj = {
   'foo': 'bash'
}
// obj => { 'foo': 'bash' }
```

In the above snippet the `obj` variable's value is *reset* using an object literal.

```
var obj = { 'baz': 'bar' };
obj.foo = 'bash';

// obj => { 'baz': 'bar', 'foo': 'bash' }
```

In the above example the original object is *extended* by using dot notation.

> i try console.log(constructorFunction.a); but it returns undefined.

That's because you haven't created an instance. The `a` is property of the constructor's `prototype` object.

```
console.log(constructorFunction.prototype.a);
```

If you create an instance object then `a` is a property of that instance.

```
var ins = new constructorFunction();
console.log(ins.a);
```

Comment: But i can't accept those properties, i try console.log(constructorFunction.a); but it returns undefined.

Comment: I am thinking that the constructorFunction is extended with triangle object and i could acces to it, couldn't i?

Comment: @AlanasMacijauskas You can access it as: `constructorFunction.prototype.a`. Remember, you didn't assign `triangle` to `constructorFunction` but to `constructorFunction.prototype`.

Comment: thank you, i got it now!